# JqGrid: Send All Grid Data (including all rows) to Server on Save

Tags: spring-mvc, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid heavily in our project. We have this very unique requirement and I am investigating whether there is really any solution to the specific use case and needed some inputs on it.

Here's the scenario:

1. jqGrid loads data which is loaded from the server (via Spring).
2. The first row in the grid allows you to add a new row to the grid (new additions are made locally and not persisted to the DB).
3. Each row has a inline save and a delete icon. On clicking the inline-save icon the grid data would be saved locally (i.e. changes are not reflected to DB). On clicking the inline-delete icon, the row would be removed locally (changes would not be persisted to the database).
4. Each row is draggable so that their positions can be interchanged (however the position are not immediately persisted to the database).
5. Just below the jqGrid, we have a save button, which when clicked, will send all the grid data to the server.

Is there really a solution for the above use case ? i.e. Loading grid data from the database, then making changes to the grid (Add/Edit/Delete/Reorder) locally. And finally saving data back to the database.

I'd really appreciate if there could be any examples for implementing this use case.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is an old question. But it will benefit to those who need it. I believe there is few threads already about processing global data grid to server. I had the same request and had to solve it.

I only implement it in edit mode without using inline feature. The add/delete feature is handled with refreshing the grid and not saved locally.

You will need to implement code on server to process the whole data grid, parse the json array data from the client. In my case, row by row to extract the row data and map it to corresponding bean on the server, map the values to the model object so you can perform save operation for each row.

In order to do that, I add a custom button called "Save all" with a reminder message to the user to save manually each row he or she modifies so that json data grid values will be correctly retrieved and posted to the server.

Below is an example of how to write such function on the client side, for the server, you will need to write your own restful web service to handle save operation.

```
var executeGlobalSave = function () {

       var gridData = jQuery(grid_selector).getRowData();
        var postData = JSON.stringify(gridData);
        console.log("JSON serialized jqGrid data:\n" + postData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: URLUpdateAll,
            data : {
                jgGridData: postData
            },
            dataType:"json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });

};
```

Hope it helps!